# Duplicate Contact on Lead detail lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, aura

I have requirement where lead is coming from  webservice through form on one of our  site .So,when lead is coming i have some dedup rules to check against existing contact.So till here everthing is working fine like am creating webservice to accepts leads data and then created some dedup rules to avoid bad data.but negative scenario if found i need to tie with a contact on lead detail page

But here my question is once I find any duplicate i need to tie that contact with the new lead in lightning detail page.Is that possible through custom component?

Please any suggestions whether my requirement is valid to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will create a lookup field on contact to tie it to lead, you can easily show contact in "related list" of lead detail page.

But I think tying contact back to lead is not a good option. Ideally you should merge lead with already existing contact. Unfortunately, the "merge" statement in apex work with same object types (meaning you can merge contacts with contacts or accounts with accounts).

If you know how to write apex you can also give a thought to automatically converting lead to existing contact (as far as I know, if you provide correct contactId in lead conversion lead gets merged with contact)

Here's link to LeadConvert class

[LeadConvertClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_dml_convertLead)